# mysql all data from 5 tables WHERE

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 5 tables:

1) games:

```
g_id | country | league | tour | team1 | team2 | and other...
```

2) events:

```
e_id | name | eTime | g_id | and other...
```

3) and other tables, and here a query:

```
SELECT * FROM games 
  INNER JOIN events ON games.g_id = events.g_id 
  INNER JOIN stats ON games.g_id = stats.g_id
  INNER JOIN lineups ON games.g_id = lineups.g_id
  INNER JOIN ads ON games.g_id = ads.g_id
WHERE games.team1 = 'Арсенал'
```

After this query no result, phpmyadmin like depends with message "Loading..." but no answer.

Whats wrong? Maybe i need any another query?
Help me pls.

Comment: If you change `SELECT *` to `SELECT COUNT(*)`, what result do you get?

Comment: Does all the table contain the elements with same `g_id`

Comment: **@MarkBannister** with LEFT JOIN result  = count 4441740 but so slow... any faster solution?

Comment: **@Sourabh** yes all tables have it

Comment: i suspect then that  `Арсенал` is causing the problem how did you store that in the database, in normal varchar?

Comment: The result of the `count(*)` query is telling you that there are over 4 million rows of data - do you really want to return that many rows of data?

Comment: **@MarkBannister** no i need only like 1000 rows, but what query can do that?

Answer (score 0):

Use `left join`s instead of `inner join`s. If any of the joined tables do not contain the game, then no result will be produced.

My guess is that you never have all tables relate to a game, but only some of them.

Comment: i was tryed! result the some

Answer (score 0):

If you want all the data for Arsenal's games from the associated tables, then I suggest splitting the query up into four different queries - like so:

```
SELECT * FROM games 
INNER JOIN events ON games.g_id = events.g_id 
WHERE games.team1 = 'Арсенал';

SELECT * FROM games 
INNER JOIN stats ON games.g_id = stats.g_id
WHERE games.team1 = 'Арсенал';

SELECT * FROM games 
INNER JOIN lineups ON games.g_id = lineups.g_id
WHERE games.team1 = 'Арсенал';

SELECT * FROM games 
INNER JOIN ads ON games.g_id = ads.g_id
WHERE games.team1 = 'Арсенал';
```